# Increase gyroscope data collection on Chrome in Android

Tags: javascript, android, gyroscope

Environment: Chrome browser on Android.

I've been trying to collect data from the gyroscope at a speed of 30fps, but no matter how fast I call the function, the new data doesn't go anywhere close to that. I mean, you can call the API as much as you want, but you'll get duplicated data.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns the constructor has a frequency parameter I didn't see. Someone else pointed it out to me.

I add both options, for the gyroscope alone and the Absolute Orientation Sensor

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gyroscope
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbsoluteOrientationSensor

Thanks